# git commands for two working versions

Tags: git, workflow, branching-and-merging

I am working with a collaborator on some code that, as far as I know, produces good output. In this code, we have a function that takes a variable `vals_dB` that represents a 2D array of the logarithm of the magnitude of some complex floats. For reasons that are not relevant, we'd like to refactor the code so that the function takes `vals_cpx`, so that the function also receives the phase information.

My question is, what is the best git workflow model for this? We may or may not end up using the function with the modified argument, but we'd like to at least see if it works and check it against the old output (which has been tested and is working the way it should). Should we use branching? Or just keep track of the commits and return to a previous state if we decide to go back to the original?

About me, I've been using git to share code with others for awhile, but due to constant deadlines I never have the chance to sit down and really think about what I'm doing. As a result, my working trees usually end up in a state of disarray and I end up with a bunch of heinous merge conflicts.

Comment: Create a "feature" branch - and then after testing the new function, you can merge back into the current branch where you'd have the function that takes a variable `vals_dB`.

Comment: I used p4merge and did the merge visually. Piece of cake! I don't know why I was so scared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @ishmaelMakitla said, you should create a feature branch using `git checkout -b <branch-name>`. Then you develop your feature on that branch, test it, see if you like it, etc. If not, you just do `git checkout master` to go back to your main branch, then do `git branch -D <branch-name>` to delete the feature branch like it never existed. And you can keep doing development on `master` while you're at it, too!